# MultiChoiceModeListener not working

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to implement `MultiChoiceModeListener` for select multiple item from a `ListView`. My current progress is shown below. But it doesn't working. It has no action on even long press. is any thing missed in my code or anything wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class FragmentFavorite extends Fragment {

    ListView lvFavoriteItems;
    Activity mActivity = null;
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("My name is a", "My name is b",
            "My name is c", "My name is d", "My name is e", "My name is f"));
    ArrayList<String> phone = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("9895653263", "9895653264", "9895653265",
            "9895653266", "9895653267", "9895653267"));

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(mActivity == null) {
            this.mActivity = getActivity();
        }
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorite_list, container, false);
        lvFavoriteItems = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.lv_item_list);
        FavoriteAdapter fav = new FavoriteAdapter();
        lvFavoriteItems.setAdapter(fav);
        lvFavoriteItems.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        lvFavoriteItems.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new FavMultiChoiceModeListener());
        return root;
    }

    private class FavoriteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return names.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View listItem;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                listItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item_2_line, null);
            } else {
                listItem = convertView;
            }
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
            tv1.setText(names.get(position));
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);
            tv2.setText(phone.get(position));
            listItem.setId(position);
            return listItem;
        }    }

    private class FavMultiChoiceModeListener implements ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int i, long l, boolean b) {
            final int checkedCount = lvFavoriteItems.getCheckedItemCount();
            mode.setSubtitle("" + checkedCount + " items selected ");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mActivity.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.selection_menu, menu);
            actionMode.setTitle("Select Items");
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Clicked " + menuItem.getTitle(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're extending from BaseAdapter, you might need to call `convertView.setLongClickable(true)` in your `getView` method.